# jQuery Ajax complete event response is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cors

I am facing one issue while getting response from the server from Ajax call , response is coming null from the Ajax request this is happening to  a particular user not for all users, I am making a **CORS** request  and no error is coming on the other server **data.responseJSON** is coming null complete event is getting executed not error event can any one let me know what is the issue Thanks in advance.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: urlToUpdateTEID,
            data: JSON.stringify({ 
                "isNonDicomCase":self.IsNonDicomCase,
            }),
            // data: { "allCaseDetail": JSON.stringify(cases) },
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            complete: function (data) {

                LogMessage("NJUCommonFunctions UpdateMddxID Ajax call to rename file END " + data );

                if (data.responseJSON.success == true && data.responseJSON.UploadedCases != null && data.responseJSON.UploadedCases != '') {


                }  
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                LogMessage("NJUCommonFunctions UpdateMddxID  Ajax ERROR BLOCK jqXHR " +jqXHR + 'exception ' +exception);


            }
        });
```

Comment: Replace `complete` with `success` and `console` some value and make sure your request is working properly

Comment: Provide the request function code  and describe

Comment: Will  use success event and try , i am wondering y this issue is coming for a particular user that user is using Google chrome browser. this line is getting executed LogMessage("NJUCommonFunctions UpdateMddxID Ajax call to rename file END " + data ); and i am making a CORS request

Comment: Can you please provide the url function and define it